# React: Set Weight Preference for entire site

Tags: reactjs

I am building an app, and on various fields (for labels etc) - I have the words kg (ie. Weight (kg))

If I allow the user a simple toggle to set kg or lbs - how would I then assign this to the rest of the app? So if they have select lbs then it replaces all instances of the word kg (labels, fields, text)

I can put various if else statements with every label - but was hoping for something a little more robust then that.

Comment: I think you could use React's Context API, that weight preference state would be shared throughout all of your application, i.e. all of your components would have access to that preference data. Context is also used for other general aspects like the theme shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) which is built in reactjs :

```js
// Create a Context
const UnitContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  // Add a state
  const [unit, setUnit] = useState("kg");
  // Use the Provider to make state available
  // to every children & grandchildren
  return (
    <UnitContext.Provider value={[unit, setUnit]}>
      <div>
        <Children />
      </div>
    </UnitContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Children() {
  // Use the Consumer to grab the value from context
  const [unit, setUnit] = useContext(UnitContext);
  return (
    <>
      <div>The unit is {unit}</div>
      <GrandChildren />

      <input
        value="Change to lbs"
        type="button" 
        onClick={(e => setUnit(e.target.name))} 
        name="lbs"
      />
      <input
        value="Change to kg"
        type="button" 
        onClick={(e => setUnit(e.target.name))} 
        name="kg"
      />
    </>
  );
}

function GrandChildren() {
  const [unit] = useContext(UnitContext);
  return (
    <>
      <div>The unit is still {unit}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hooks UseContext Example (forked)]